# Why does Vr increase with lower air density and decrease with higher air density?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, performance-calculation, v-speeds

Can someone explain why Vr increase with lower air density and decrease with higher air density? I read such a phrase in my ATPL(A) performance textbook, but without further explanation. As far as I know Vr is an indicated airspeed, so it should be independent from air density.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Part of* Part 25's [definition](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.107) of VR is:

> The speed (determined in accordance with § 25.111(c)(2)) that allows reaching V2 before reaching a height of 35 feet above the takeoff surface

At lower air density the engine produces **less thrust** (less air to burn), so to arrive at the same height at the same location while reaching V2, a better lift to drag ratio is needed, i.e. same lift with **less drag,** which needs a slightly faster speed to allow a smaller angle of attack.

To put that into perspective, for the Boeing 737-800 the increment is *approximately* **one** knot for every 2,000 feet increase in elevation:

> [image]

Lettered areas are the corrections A through E:

> [image]

And above are example numbers for the correction columns A through E. Very subtle.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for the research.